# The problem is ngrx variable cannot be used outside the selector body

Tags: angular

The problem is ngrx that inside the selector body a value is assigned to a variable within the class, but it cannot be used outside the selector body

**Component.ts**

```
    export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() loading: boolean=false;
  Profile= {} as  Profile;
  user = {} as User;
  data:any
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {
    this.store.select(getUser).subscribe((data:any)=>this.user=data);
    this.store.select(getloadingProfile).subscribe(data=>{
      this.spinner.show();
      if(!data){
      this.loading=data;
      this.spinner.hide();
    }});
      }
  ngOnInit() {
 this.store.select(getloadingProfile).subscribe((dataProfile:any)=> {
  this.Profile=dataProfile;
  console.log(this.Profile); //<--Here it prints the data inside the selector body
 });
console.log(this.Profile); //<--here does not print
}

}
```

this is:
**selector.ts**

```
 import { ProfileState } from '../state/Profile.state';
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { selectAll } from '../reducers/Profile.reducers';

export const Profile_STATE_NAME = 'Profile';
const getProfileState = createFeatureSelector<ProfileState>(Profile_STATE_NAME);
export const getProfile = createSelector(getProfileState, selectAll);
export const getProfileEntities = createSelector(
  getProfileState,
  (state) => state.Profile
);
export const getloadingProfile = createSelector(getProfileState, (state) => state.ProfileLoaded);
export const selectProfileError = createSelector(getProfileState, (state) => state.error);
```

this is:
**Action.ts**

```
 import { EntityState, createEntityAdapter, EntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { ProfileModule } from 'src/app/profile/profile.module';
import { Profile } from '../../models/Profile.model';

export interface ProfileState extends EntityState<Profile> {
  ProfileLoaded: boolean;
  Profile:Profile;
  error: boolean;
}
export const ProfileAdapter: EntityAdapter<Profile> = createEntityAdapter<Profile>({
  selectId: (customer: Profile) => customer.id
});
export const initialState: ProfileState = ProfileAdapter.getInitialState({
  ProfileLoaded: true,
  error: false,
  Profile:{} as Profile
});
```

this is:
**state.ts**

```
  import { EntityState, createEntityAdapter, EntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { ProfileModule } from 'src/app/profile/profile.module';
import { Profile } from '../../models/Profile.model';

export interface ProfileState extends EntityState<Profile> {
  ProfileLoaded: boolean;
  Profile:Profile;
  error: boolean;
}
export const ProfileAdapter: EntityAdapter<Profile> = createEntityAdapter<Profile>({
  selectId: (customer: Profile) => customer.id
});
export const initialState: ProfileState = ProfileAdapter.getInitialState({
  ProfileLoaded: true,
  error: false,
  Profile:{} as Profile
});
```

this is:
**reducer.ts**

```
 import {loadProfileSuccess,loadProfileFail,} from '../actions/Profile.actions';
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { initialState, ProfileAdapter } from '../state/Profile.state';
const _ProfileReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
    on(loadProfileSuccess, (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      Profile:action.profile,
      ProfileLoaded: false
    })),
  on(loadProfileFail, (state) => {
    return ProfileAdapter.removeAll({
      ...state,
      error: true,
      loading: false,
    });
  }),
);
export const { selectAll, selectIds } = ProfileAdapter.getSelectors();
export function ProfileReducer(state:any, action:any) {
  return _ProfileReducer(state, action);
}
```

this is:
**Effect.ts**

```
 @Injectable()
export class ProfileEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private PagesService: PagesService,
  ) { }

  loadProfile$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(loadProfile),
      
      concatMap(() => this.PagesService.GetProfile()),
      map((Profile:Profile) => {
        return loadProfileSuccess({ profile:Profile })
      },
        catchError((error) => of(loadProfileFail(error))))
    )
  );
}
```

this is:
**resolver.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ProfileResolver implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { }
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.store
      .pipe(
        select(getloadingProfile),
        tap((loadProfileSuccess) => {
          if (loadProfileSuccess) {
            console.log(loadProfileSuccess);
            this.store.dispatch(loadProfile());
          }
        }),
        first()
      );
  }
}
```

Please help me as soon as possible, thank you

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to print value for `this.Profile` before it is assigned a value. Can you try print its value in ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle hook?

Comment: The observable of your selector emits events asynchronously, that means your subscribe callback is not invoked immediately. At the time when you try to print out your variable, which is at this point still not initialized you will see the empty object.

Comment: @Phalgun 
It still prints the value blank after trying what you said

Comment: @RomanP.
What is the solution please?

Comment: There a many solutions for this, one possible you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you init your initial profile state with **null** then you can do something like that:

```js
this.store.select(getloadingProfile).pipe(
  filter(Boolean),
  take(1),
).subscribe((profile) => console.log('Your Profile', profile));
```

That would subscribe to your observable, filter the initial value until it will be initialized with something truthy, then it will take the first emission, print it to the console and unsubscribe.

**Every time when you subscribe to an observable, you also have to unsubscribe from it.**

In the first example the **take** operator will unsubscribe for you.

But I would you suggest to work with the observable in your template with a **async pipe**, this would subscribe / unsubscribe for you.

e.g.:

```html
<div *ngIf="ProfileObs$ | async as profile">
  <span>Name: {{ profile.name }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It still does not work to update the new values, but in the template it displays the values, but I cannot do any operation in the upcoming data because it gives null values. Is there a solution? I know I'm tired of you

Comment: Which values do you mean? Your local variables of your class?
Do you dispatch the action, which is triggering your effect?
Is the right data in your state?

A StackBlitz example would be nice.

Comment: Thank you, the problem has been resolved. The problem was that I was using canActivate with Resolver. It got deleted
canActivate as it was allowed to cross into the component before loading the profile data